# Concatenating of Strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have task to implement method returning string.Contact(str1, str2, str3), but in the list of test cases i observe, that some of them have more than 3 input arguments (actually 4 and 5). I don't have idea, what algorithm i should write (because in msdn i didn't see anything similiar). Appreciate all help.

My sample :

```
   public static string ConcatenateStrings(string str1, string str2, string str3)
    {
        return string.Concat(str1 + str2 + str3);
    }
```

Code of TestCases :

```
 [TestCase("", "", "", ExpectedResult = "")]
    [TestCase("a", "b", "c", ExpectedResult = "abc")]
    [TestCase("abc", "bcd", "cde", ExpectedResult = "abcbcdcde")]
    public string ConcatenateStrings_ThreeParameters_ParametersAreValid_ReturnsResult(string str1, string str2, string str3)
    {
        // Act
        return ConcatenatingStrings.ConcatenateStrings(str1, str2, str3);
    }

    [TestCase("", "", "", "", ExpectedResult = "")]
    [TestCase("a", "b", "c", "d", ExpectedResult = "abcd")]
    [TestCase("abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", ExpectedResult = "abcbcdcdedef")]
    public string ConcatenateStrings_ThreeParameters_ParametersAreValid_ReturnsResult(string str1, string str2, string str3, string str4)
    {
        // Act
        return ConcatenatingStrings.ConcatenateStrings(str1, str2, str3, str4);
    }
```

Result of TestCases :

[image]

Comment: Maybe the best way is to write Range, but what scopes?

Comment: The expression `str1 + str2 + str3` where `strN` is a string will evaluate to the concatenation of those three strings.  If you want to concatenate more than a handful of strings, consider `System.Text.StringBuilder`.  Straight up string concatenation results in a lot of _garbage_ being created that will eventually need to be _garbage collected_

Comment: You say that you don't see anything similar and yet you're already using `string.Concat`, which has the behavior that you want.  Just look at it and see what *it* does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `params` keyword, you can pass an array into your method.

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

```
public static string ConcatenateStrings(params string[] str)
{
    string concat;

    foreach(string s in str)
    {
        concat = string.Concat(concat, s);
    }

    return concat;
}
```

Comment: It's good solution, but i can't change parameteres in methods.

Comment: If you can't change the method signature, then there isn't a way that I know of to pass your test case.  The `params` keyword will allow your test cases to pass.  In fact, my example can be simplified even further to `return string.Concat(str);`